# How to transfer file from one disk to another in Apple //e (Applewin)

Tags: apple-ii, apple-dos, pascal

For the nostalgia, I'm going through *Apple Pascal - A Hands-on Approach* using AppleWin.

There are four disks, `pascal0` through `pascal3`, and for some reason `pascal0` is missing a file called `SYSTEM.PASCAL`. It's present on`pascal1`, however.

I thought I could boot a normal DOS disk, load `SYSTEM.PASCAL` from `pascal1`, and save it on `pascal0`, but when I try to `catalog` the `pascal1` disk it produces gibberish and beeps.

So how do I copy `SYSTEM.PASCAL` from one disk to another? AppleWin has a two-disk-drive configuration.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Apple Pascal is an entirely different operating system from DOS, including different on-disk file formats. So it won't be possible to use DOS utilities to copy files, as you found.

Comment: Since you're using AppleWin, on Windows the easiest way would be to use a Windows-based Apple II disk utility like [CiderPress](https://a2ciderpress.com/) instead of doing it inside the emulator. I don't know the Apple Pascal environment well enough to help do this inside the emulator off the top of my head without some research.

Comment: Thanks! I found a book called "Apple Pascal Operating System Reference Manual." There should be a way to do this within the system (but I might just give up and use CiderPress).

Comment: There is a disk utility somewhere that you can use to copy files; I'd have to fire up an emulator myself to remember the details. But you don't *need* to copy `SYSTEM.PASCAL`; the whole system is set up so you can have one of the disks (pascal1 or pascal2, don't remember) in the left drive, and your work disk in the right drive. From time to time you may need to switch disks to access rarely used stuff.

Comment: I started up https://archive.org/details/UCSD_Pascal_1.1_1, and copying files is done with `T(ransfer` in `F(ile`, IIRC. Archive doesn't seem to support a second disk, so I can't test.

Comment: See the [reference manual](https://mirrors.apple2.org.za/Apple%20II%20Documentation%20Project/Software/Languages/Apple%20II%20Pascal/Manuals/Apple%20Pascal%20Operating%20System%20Reference%20Manual.pdf), page 34.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should download and use [CiderPress](https://a2ciderpress.com/features.htm#disks) which is a Swiss Army Knife tool for Apple disk images - It understands and supports the UCSD Pascal file system format and should be able to transfer a file from one disk image to the other.

Comment: As @dirkt noted, Apple Pascal was generally run on a two-drive system. You'd boot `APPLE1:` and run the asm/compiler/linker from `APPLE2:`. IIRC `APPLE0:` was intended for a one-drive system, and looking at disk listings it *should* have `SYSTEM.PASCAL` on it. FWIW, Pascal v1.3 supports installation on a 3.5" disk and uses 128KB of RAM when available, which makes life easier.